# On a VPS where two sites are hosted, why does the CNAME of one resolve to the website of the other?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have a server setup where two sites are virtually hosted. They share the same IP address, of course, and the server runs Plesk to manage the sites.

DNS is setup so that @ A points to the ip address 119.82.29.130. www CNAME is setup to point to nagoyatax.com. That's website one. When you visit nagoyatax.com or www.nagoyatax.com the website for this domain shows up correctly.

website 2:

DNS is setup so that @ A points to the ip address 119.82.29.130. www CNAME is setup to point to tourismbuilder.com. Now here is the weirdness. tourismbuilder.com correctly points to the tourismbuilder.com website. However, www.tourismbuilder.com points shows the natoyatax.com website.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?  Not a DNS guru so let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that you don't have a `ServerAlias` setup for `www.tourismbuilder.com` within the `tourismbuilder.com` vhost definition.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ...
    ServerName tourismbuilder.com
    ServerAlias www.tourismbuilder.com

    ...
```

and the reason you see the `nagoyatax.com` is that it is the first vhost defined and is then the default vhost.

---

From the comments. Plesk has a `www` checkbox that will create a suitable ServerAlias if checked.

Comment: This was the issue. There is a 'WWW' checkbox available when creating a new site. I forgot to check that box and this the ServerAlias directive was not added. Just a heads up to anyone using Plesk and get the same issues. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS seems to be correctly set up:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.tourismbuilder.com.        IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.tourismbuilder.com. 14400   IN  CNAME   tourismbuilder.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
tourismbuilder.com. 14400   IN  A   119.82.29.130
```

If you run Apache as your web server, I would say that the issue lies within the configuration of the web server.

The reason that the first site works on both names is most likely that it is the first vhost, which causes Apache to default to it if it doesn't have a match.

Try opening the vhost configuration for tourismbuiler.com and add this line

```
ServerAlias www.tourismbuilder.com
```

Right underneath the "ServerName" line.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot edit the DNS zones manually (and change the  www CNAME record for tourismbuilder.com) then you need to submit a ticket to your hosting provider.

I would suspect that a script was used to generate the zone files on creation of the site or account; perhaps it was entered incorrectly or there's a parsing bug of some sort.

Comment: I have ssh access to the server. Is it possible to check that way? What file would I look at? Cent OS is the OS

Comment: It's very unlikely you would be able to edit the zone files from your SSH access.  You're more than likely jailed in your home directory.